# how to search particular value and modify it in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to travel a pandas DataFrame ,and search special values meanwhile modify it with a expression and replace it with operation result . for example:

```
   A    B
0  1    3
1  37   45
2  3    5
```

for each element i of DataFrame ,while i>10, new_value=old_value%10,  modify the DataFrame as:

```
   A    B
0  1    3
1  7    5
2  3    5
```

search in google, only a simple Function df.replace(a,b) for modify.Are there any Function for this question?

Comment: Do you want to repalce all the values when greater than 10 or just the values in first and second row?

Comment: @Mohammad Yusuf Ghazi, replace all values that meet filter result. the above example is very simple for explaining my purpose. In general, I want to use a expression to calculate filtered valude then replace it with expression result.

Comment: @Posh_Pumpkin Not a duplicate to that one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x%10 if x>10 else x)
```

`applymap()` will traverse through each element in DataFrame.

Comment: This will be very, very slow for large data.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Shall I delete this then or leave it to demonstrate how to do conditionally?

Comment: thank you very much. This Function could reach my aim.I just want to operate many text format meteorology data. It is not large but contain amount files.

Comment: @Cobin Yes. I didn't read your comment in the question. Yes `applymap()` is what you want.

Comment: @Mohammad Yusuf Ghazi, additional question, when 'applymap()' traverse Dataframe, how to return the index of element ?

Comment: @Cobin Nope `applymap()` wont give you the index. You will have to iter through rows and columns to get the index. You can do something like this: `for a in df.itertuples():
    print a
    print a.Index, a.A, a.B
    if a.A > 10:
        df.loc[a.Index,'A'] = a.A%10
    if a.B > 10:
        df.loc[a.Index,'B'] = a.B%10
df`

Comment: @Mohammad Yusuf Ghazi, you give me another way to tranverse the DataFrame. besides modify the element, I need to know the Index of this element. Because some elements are Nodata, I should fill these elements using 'interpolation' method,such as calculate the average values of 4 elements that around 'goal element'. So I want to know the Index( perhaps ' coodination' ) of this DataFrame. Maybe I should ask a new question for solving my problem.

Answer (score 6):

Given that the `% 10` operation does nothing for values less than 10, by far the fastest way to do this will be to simply operate on the entire frame at once:

```
df = df % 10
```

Comment: I was just going to post `df.loc[df.A > 10] %= 10`.  But you are right, `> 10` is pointless.

Comment: Duh. I did unnecessary checking. :D

Comment: Nice! I wll try it.

Answer (score 0):

If the "traveling" part is important, then you kinda have to loop it. There really isn't a way to "loop" faster. I guess there may be some performance difference between, say, `for lab, row in df.iterrows()` and `for item in lst`, but it would be minimal.

But if your goal is to modify the value, then you can do so in one go. You can use @John Zwinck's answer if the example you provided with us (the modulo) is exactly what you need because modulo won't touch any numbers that are small than the operand. x % y = x as long as x < y.

But if your example is a bad representation of what you actually need and you're looking to do other operations where the condition statement is mandatory, you could do something called boolean indexing. In that case, you can do this:

```
df[df['A'] > 10] += 10 #I changed the operation so I don't look silly
```